# How to debug test from test explorer window in visual studio with Nunit runner

Tags: nunit, test-explorer

How can I debug my nunit test listed in  test explorer in visual studio.I have  added nunit adapter  and tests are listed in explorer,but if I start debugging  fixture from explorer it runs using Vstest.execution engine,is it possible to make explorer use nunit runner?though Vstest.execution engine recognises nunit i want tio run using Nunit runner

Answer (score 0):

When VsTest runs NUnit tests, it is using the NUnit adapter that you have installed, which calls the NUnit execution engine.

Is there something particular that is not working for you in running tests this way that you need some help with?

Comment: Thanks for response :-) while debugging i can see vstest.discovery and vstest.executionengine  process running in task manager,if i end those task my debugging  session ends.

Comment: If i start debugging by  clicking start button in VS or F5 with start program path set to nunit.exe in debug project property window. test runs fine...if start debugging  by right clicking on fixture in test explorer it fails to load some .dll belonging to theird party called TestQuest...

Comment: I added adapter by downloading  nuget package to local folder  and making that folder as nuget source....did i miss adding any thing else?

Comment: From Google search, TestQuest seems to be a commercial testing solution. If it was installed on your computer in the past, it may not have been properly removed. Or if it's still installed, the installation may be corrupted.